# Is there a similar tool to Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

Do you know any application that is similar as Selenium, both commerical and open source?

Can you recommend me any application except Selenium?

Comment: Similar in what respect?  What are you looking for?  What environment do you have? What programming skills do you have? PLease describe your needs other than 'like selenium' which is too vague.  If you could be more specific we can better answer your question :)

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/selenium/

Comment: Why selenium is not a good fit? This will give us idea what you are asking

Comment: Well, in my case I strongly believe that there are other tool that I also would like to learn about. For instance there are different database.

Answer (score 1):

Not much that is really well known, but there are a few things.

http://alternativeto.net/software/selenium/

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."